# Need to 404 a page with an ellipses (...) in the URL using .htaccess

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I have a url that google has indexed that looks like `http://example.com/someth…/` with those ellipses just like that. No, it's not just 3 periods. I'm trying to 404 the page in the .htaccess but I don't know how to match an ellipses.

I have tried `RedirectMatch 404 ^/someth\x2026/` but it doesn't work.

Anyone know how to match an ellipses using regex?

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<FilesMatch /include(/?|/.*)>
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
</FilesMatch>

RedirectMatch 404 ^/include(/?|/.*)$
```

Comment: Could you please explain what each part of the above code does / the logic behind it? I'd like to understand it before I try it and to also make sure it won't affect any other URLs.

Answer (score 0):

Try using URL encoding (of the UTF-8 encoded char), eg:

```
^/?someth%E2%80%A6/
```

Check your server log for the exact URL the request is using.

Comment: I checked the server logs and the URL being fetched is indeed /someth%E2%80%A6/ but using RedirectMatch 404 ^/?someth%E2%80%A6/ still doesn't work. I can't figure out why. All my other 404s work fine.